# how to preaper correct mongodb schema

Tags: mongodb

I want to ask for advice how to setup mongodb schema properly.

Puprose for my app is to track people FTE per project for each month.

Example I want it in table fashion for each user. And each table will cover whole year like below

```
2019
           Jan     Feb       Mar
Project1   0.5FTE  05FTE    0.7fte
Project2   0.5FTE  05FTE    0.3fte
```

Can I ask for advice if my schema will do the job? Or i need to make addjustments

```
const YearSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refs: 'users'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },

    project: [{

        title: {
            type: String,
            // required: true
        },
        months: [{
            january: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            february: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            march: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            april: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            may: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            june: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            july: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            august: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            october: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            november: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },
            december: {
                type: String,
                default: 0
            },

        }],
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach if are not concern with More the one schema .

```
var projectSchema = new Schema ({
    userId : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refs: 'users'},
    projectTitle : {type : String , required : true},
    name : {type : String ,  required : true},
    date : { type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

//your Yearly Schema 
//add necessary field in Yearly Schema .
var yearlySchema = new Schema ({
    userId : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refs: 'users'},
    projectId : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refs: 'projects'},
    monthName : {type: String,default: 0}   
});
```

The problem with your earlier schema was when there will be bulk of data , you will need more `for loop` of get the desired result . 
Earlier i faced the same dificulty in `for loop` with the kind of `schema` you provided . 


Therefore , I suggest you to use more than one schema instead of single Schema . 

Hope , this will helpful to you .

Comment: how can i assosiate year and prject i mean how can i query to get year and project associate with it?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what kinda query you are wishing or what you are worried about ? @Exc